# ChromeDriver, Chromium, python: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: python, web-scraping, cgi, selenium-chromedriver

Until recently I used phantomJS to do some scraping via CGI scripts on my web server (Centos 7 64Bit). Since it was discontinued and I ran into some errors with it, I wanted to change to chromedriver. But I couldn't get it to run so far.

The error that I get is:

```
Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
```

When I look into the verbose log files it seems to fail here:

```
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
/home/myName/chrome_binaries
```

I use chromedriver `2.37` and downloaded the newest chromium binaries `v545142`. I use python `3.5` and selenium `3.6`.

This is my script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5
import sys
import traceback
import cgitb
import time
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from unidecode import unidecode

print ('Content-Type: text/html\n')
print ()
sys.stderr = sys.stdout
cgitb.enable()

path_to_chr="/home/myName/chrome/chromedriver"

basis_url="https://www.google.de/"
service_log_path = "chromedriver.log"
service_args = ['--verbose']
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
# options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
display = Display(visible=0, size=(640, 480))
display.start()
options.binary_location = "/home/myName/chrome_binaries"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chr,chrome_options=options,service_args=service_args,service_log_path=service_log_path)
driver.get(basis_url)
driver.close()
```

As you can see I tried basically every solution that is suggested. The files are set to be executable.

Do have you any ideas left?

Comment: Have you checked if the path of the chrome's binaries location is correct? If you list the paths contents, the actual chrome binaries are there?

Comment: @FilipeFreire I point the binary location directly at the chrome file in the directory, its chmod is 755. The driver path is directly pointed the chromedriver file, its chmod is 755. The pathes in teh script have to point at the executables right? Not just the directories where they are in? If point both pathes on the directory of the executables, I get the following error: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory